# Metadata Error in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, modis, metadata, time-series

In the below code time band doesn't create for merged collection. I don't know why but it returns metadata error:

[image]

code link: https://code.earthengine.google.com/3827c156af430c2485aedf28f9273206

```
Map.centerObject(geometry);

var temporalCollection = function(collection, start, count, interval, units){
   
  var sequences = ee.List.sequence(0,ee.Number(count).subtract(1.0));
  var originDate = ee.Date(start);
  
  return ee.ImageCollection(sequences.map(function(i){
    
    var startDate = originDate.advance(ee.Number(interval).multiply(i),units);
    var endDate = originDate.advance(ee.Number(interval).multiply(ee.Number(i).add(1)),units);
    
    return collection.filterDate(startDate, endDate).mean().clip(geometry)
    .set('systam:time_start',startDate.millis())
    .set('system:time_end', endDate.millis());
  }));
};

var AOD = function(img){
  var bands = img.select('Optical_Depth_055').multiply(0.001).clip(geometry);
  return bands.copyProperties(img,['system:time_start','system:time_end']);
};

var TIME = function(img){
  var time = ee.Image(img.metadata('system:time_start'));
  return img.addBands(time).copyProperties(img,['system:time_start','system:time_end']);
};



var modisAOD1 = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/006/MCD19A2_GRANULES")
.filterDate('2000-01-01','2011-01-01')
.filterBounds(geometry)
.map(AOD);

var modisAOD16DAYS1 = temporalCollection(modisAOD1, '2001-01-01', 228, 16, 'days');

print('MODIS AOD 16DAYS 2001-2010:',modisAOD16DAYS1);


var modisAOD2 = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/006/MCD19A2_GRANULES")
.filterDate('2011-01-01','2021-01-01')
.filterBounds(geometry)
.map(AOD);

var modisAOD16DAYS2 = temporalCollection(modisAOD2, '2011-01-01', 228, 16, 'days');

print('MODIS AOD 16DAYS 2011-2020:',modisAOD16DAYS2);


var modisAOD16DAYS = modisAOD16DAYS1.merge(modisAOD16DAYS2);

print('MODIS AOD 16 DAYS 2001-2020:',modisAOD16DAYS);


var modisAodChange = modisAOD16DAYS.map(TIME);

print(modisAodChange);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, one of those classic errors where you really don't know what is going wrong. The solution is really simple, there's a typo in your function `temporalCollection()`.

```
return collection.filterDate(startDate, endDate).mean().clip(geometry)
.set('systam:time_start',startDate.millis())
.set('system:time_end', endDate.millis());
```

In line 2 it should by `system` instead of `systam`. Something like this happened to all of us at one point, so I can definitely feel your pain.